Removing Xml nodes with a match in the sibling nodes
Trying to remove Xml nodes with a match in the sibling nodes text using xslt
my xml looks like below
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map">
    <row>
        <Name>Africa</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Name>USA</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Name>Mexico</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Name>Canada</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Name>Malaysia</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Name>Africa</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Name>Mexico</Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Name>Bangladesh</Name>
    </row>
    </root>`

and the output i need is below
   
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <root >
     <row>
      <Name>USA</Name>
     </row>
     <row>
      <Name>Canada</Name>
     </row>
     <row>
      <Name>Malaysia</Name>
     </row>
     <row>
      <Name>Bangladesh</Name>
     </row>
     </root>

`
tried below xslt but seeing Africa and Mexico in the output xml code as well. I want these two duplicated nodes along with original nodes of the same value to be removed altogether from the output
    `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
       <xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
       <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
    
    
     <xsl:template match="row[.=preceding-sibling::row/.]"/>
     </xsl:stylesheet>`

Tried this above xslt but still seeing Africa and Mexico nodes as well in the output.
Please help me to remove these nodes in the output .`

I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. Please post a new question with your new requirements and make sure that the input example is a well-formed XML document and that the required logic is clearly explained.

sure , thank you so much.

Here is one simple method:
XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="Name">
            <xsl:if test="count(current-group())=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if> 
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Here's another:
XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="row-by-name" match="row" use="Name" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="row[count(key('row-by-name', Name))=1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>


Thank you so much . This is working fine . But my requirement is below . Sorry i was not able to publish it before.

please see the original post and edited my original requirement. Sorry for not publishing the clear requirement before. Hope the question is clear now. Let me know if you have any questions.   Imagine the need to remove nodes in the xml (Africa and Mexico and Srilanka) will be with different tag names (Remove_Name) and need to remove only the remove names nodes from the Keep Names nodes only if they exists
